# Trouble showing flatness

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be a field and $\pi: K[x]/(x^2) \to K$ be the ring homomorphism given by the valuation at $0$. I'm stuck in showing that $\pi^*(K)$ (the pullback) is not a flat module (over $K[x]/(x^2)$).

Comment: Finitely presented flat modules are projective.

Flat modules over local rings are free.

But $K[x]/(x)$ is not a free $K[x]/(x^2)$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I\subset A$ an ideal.  Let us investigate whether $A/I$ is flat over $A$.

Consider the injection $0\to I\to A$ and tensor it with $A/I$.
Using $M\otimes_A A/I=M/IM$ (for any $A$-module $M$), we get the morphism of $A$-modules: $$I\otimes_AA/I\to A\otimes _AA/I  \quad\text {identified with} \quad I/I^2\to A/I: \bar i\mapsto \tilde i=\tilde 0 \quad (\bigstar)$$ Hence if $A/I$ is  flat,  $(\bigstar)$ must be injective so that  necessarily $I/I^2=0$, i.e. $I=I^2$ .
Since in our case $I=(\bar x)\neq I^2=(0)\subset A=K[x]/(x^2)=K[\bar x]$ , we conclude that: $$A/I=K \quad \text {is not flat over} \quad A=K[x]/(x^2)$$

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Glad you noticed the \bigstar. I don't really know why, but I like it and I'm happy you like it too !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I don't know why either, but it's pretty cool. I'll use it as soon as I have the opportunity!