# Does the projective Fermat curve have singular points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

I want to check if the projective Fermat curve,

$$X^n+Y^n+Z^n=0, n \geq 1$$

has singular points.

Could you give me a hint how we could do this? 
Do we have to check maybe if the curve is irreducible? If so, how could we do this?

Comment: What field are you working over?

Comment: @Hoot We are working in $K=\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you let $F(X,Y,Z) = X^n+Y^n+Z^n$, the singular points of the curve $C = \{ F = 0\}$ are defined by having all its derivatives equal to $0$, that is, $P \in C$ is a singular point if and only if
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(P) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(P) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(P) = 0
\end{equation*}

The case $n=1$ is trivial (no such points). Let $n > 1$, check that the only possible point is $[0,0,0]$, but this point does not live in the projective space.

Hence this curve has no singular points.

Comment: So, for $n=1$ it is like that:

$$F(X,Y,Z)=X+Y+Z$$

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{X}}=1$$

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Y}}=1$$

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Z}}=1$$

So, we cannot find a $P$ such that $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{X}}(P)=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Y}}(P)=\frac{\partial{F}}{ \partial{Z} }(P)=0$, right?

$$$$
For $n>1$, is it like that?

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{X}}=nX^{n-1}$$



$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Y}}=nY^{n-1}$$




$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Z}}=nZ^{n-1}$$

Comment: Is it like that?

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{X}}(P)=0 \Rightarrow nX^{n-1}=0 \Rightarrow X=0$$



$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Y}}(P)=0 \Rightarrow nY^{n-1}=0 \Rightarrow Y=0$$

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{Z}}(P)=0 \Rightarrow nZ^{n-1}=0 \Rightarrow Z=0$$


If so, could you explain me why $[0,0,0]$ does not live in the projective space?

Comment: Yes, this is so, and by definition of the projective space $[0,0,0]$ is not in there, do you know the definition of it?

Comment: Klaramun Could you maybe explain me the definition?

Comment: Yes. Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space of dimension $n+1$. We define the projective space of $V$ (or simply the projectivization of $V$) $\mathbb{P}(V) = \mathbb{P}_V^n$ as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}_V^n = V \backslash \{ 0 \} / \sim
\end{equation*}
where the equivalence relation $\sim$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
v \sim w \text{ if and only if } v = \lambda w \text{ for some } \lambda \in k^*
\end{equation*}
That is, $\mathbb{P}_V^n$ is simply the set of $1-$dimensional subvector spaces of $V$.

Comment: Klaramun So, how could we justify it formally that there are no singular points?

Comment: As some other people have noticed, it depends on the field you are working with. If it has characteristic $0$, then the argument I gave to you is completely formal (recall $[0,0,0]$ is not in the projective space simply by definition, we are excluding the $0$ vector from $V$). If the field has characteristic $p > 0$, then the same argument can work only if $p$ does not divide $n$ (see the answer below).

Comment: We are working in $K=\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So here you have it,

Answer (score 5):

If the curve $C$ is defined over a field $k$ , then $C$ is smooth unless the characteristic of the field is a prime number $p$ **and** that characteristic divides $n$, namely $n=p\nu$ for some $0\neq n\in \mathbb N$.

a) In this latter case the curve is non reduced, since its equation is $(x^\nu+y^\nu+z^\nu)^p=0$, and thus certainly not smooth.
b) If on the other hand $char (k)=0$ or $char(k)=p\gt0$ but $p$ does not divide $n$, then $C$ is smooth and thus irreducible.

Comment: We are working in $K=\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.