# Hilbert function and homogenous polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

Let $\{[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[0:0:1],[1:1:1] \} = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ be four points in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$. For every $p_i$, show there is a homogenous polynomial $f_i$ such that $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f_i(p_j) \neq 0 &  i= j\\ 
 f_i(p_j) = 0 & i \neq j
\end{matrix}\right..$$

Now if $I$ is the ideal associated with these four points, then the Hilbert function $H(R/I,t) = 4$ for all $t > 1$.

I was thinking $f_i = x_1x_2x_3 + x_i^3$ might work, but the last point $[1:1:1]$ is killing me here.

Comment: You know too much (ideals, Hilbert functions): just [compute !](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041623/advice-to-young-mathematicians/1041689#1041689) And I hope the answer has resuscitated you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $f_1=(x-y)(x-z),\quad f_2=(y-z)(y-x),\quad f_3=(z-x)(z-y), \quad f_4=xz .$

**Edit**
For completeness, let me mention that:
a)  The **homogeneous ideal** of the set $S=\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ is $$I(S)=\langle z(x-y),x(y-z)\rangle  \subset k[x,y,z] $$

b) The Hilbert **polynomial** of the set $S$  is the constant polynomial  $$H(t)=4\in \mathbb Q[t]$$  c) The Hilbert **function** of the set $S$ is the function $h: \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ characterized by $$h(0)=1, h(1)=3 \operatorname {and}  h(t)=4 \operatorname {for}  t\geq 2.$$